# Recording Button Clicked over time and further playback

Tags: android

How to record the state (click) of two buttons over time. To then reproduce their clicks over time? I think this can be realized through the creation of a `.midi` file and then its further opening and playback, or can it be done through `performClick ()`?

*Piano-type applications use this feature, where you can record that you played the piano in `.midi` or `.mid` format and then play*
[example of "piano apps"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4SW9.png)

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you want to record or replay button clicks or both?

Comment: Both - record and replay. Like "piano apps" in the Google Play

Comment: You can record it simply by calling a recording method in `onClick` of the button. And for replay, I would suggest you have a separate method for playing sounds instead of performing clicks. But you can use `postDelayed` and `performClick`

Comment: Sorry for stupid question :-)  How look like recording method in ``onClick``? I search in google but dont find this

Comment: For example, you can have a list and add times when buttons are clicked.

Comment: and this record will take into account the time of each click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `ClickRecorder` that records button id and delay over a period of time.

```
data class Click(val id: Int, val timeMs: Long)

class ClickRecorder {
    var isRecording = false
    private var currentTIme: Long = 0
    private val clicks = mutableListOf<Click>()

    fun getClicks(): List<Click>? = if (!isRecording) clicks else null

    fun recordClick(id: Int) = if (isRecording) {
        val diff = System.currentTimeMillis().minus(currentTIme)
        clicks.add(Click(id, diff))
        currentTIme = System.currentTimeMillis()
    } else null

    fun start() {
        clicks.clear()
        currentTIme = System.currentTimeMillis()
        isRecording = true
    }

    fun stop() {
        isRecording = false
    }
}
```

Use the `ClickRecorder` instance in the following way:

```
val clickRecorder = ClickRecorder()

fun onRecordButtonClick(v: View) {
    val btRecord = v as Button
    when (btRecord.text) {
        RECORD -> {
            clickRecorder.start()
            btRecord.text = STOP
        }
        STOP -> {
            clickRecorder.stop()
            btRecord.text = RECORD
        }
    }
}

fun onPianoButtonsClick(v: View) {
    clickRecorder.recordClick(v.id)
}
```

After finishing recording you can access recorded clicks by `ClickRecorder.getClicks()`. To simulate the clicks you need to make `ClickPlayer`

```
class ClickPlayer() {
    private val index = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val handler = Handler()

    fun play(list: List<Click>, callback: (Click) -> Unit) {
        index.set(0)
        val runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (index.get() < list.size) {
                    val click = list[index.getAndIncrement()]
                    callback(click)
                    val nextIndex = index.get()
                    if (nextIndex < list.size) handler.postDelayed(this, list[nextIndex].timeMs)
                }
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, list[index.get()].timeMs)
    }
}
```

Use `ClickPlayer` in the following way

```
fun playRecordedClicks(clickPlayer: ClickPlayer, clicks: List<Click>) {
    clickPlayer.play(clicks) {
        findViewById<Button>(it.id).performClick()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is may help to convert combination of button click over time to midi format? so that later you can use this combination on another device, just playing a midi file?I know I still need to install the midi library (https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib)

Comment: Yes most probably you need to map each Button ID to MidiEvent